# How to plot a Partial dependency plot with sagemaker downloaded model, xgb booster object?

Tags: python, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

I have an XGBoost model trained in Sagemaker and downloaded on my local. When you unzip the tar.gz file you get a model object(booster) file.
I want to plot a Partial Dependency Plots for some features of my dataset (batch transformed with predictions) using the Sagemaker model instance. However, I get the following error.

**ValueError: 'estimator' must be a fitted regressor or classifier.**

The code that I'm using to plot the graph is as below-

```
from sklearn.inspection import partial_dependence
pardep = partial_dependence(model, X, 'num_org')
```

Here model is <xgboost.core.Booster at 0x7f9b7b9a2250>
X is a data frame of the batch -transform with ~100 columns and 'num_org' is what I want to plot with respect to predictions.

Comment: similar issue - did you find a solution?

Comment: my answer here may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72097296/cast-xgboost-booster-class-to-xgbregressor-or-load-xgbregressor-from-xgboost-boo